# Как обеспечить корректную работу валидации при перезагрузке страницы и наладить связь между props и localStorage?

Tags: vue.js, localstorage

В данном примере, в функции `getValidatePanels`, я получаю с сервера валидацию для конкретных полей и вывожу её в шаблон. В шаблоне, при первой загрузке страницы, рендерится сначала `propList: props.personalDetailsPanelArr`. При расфокусировке валидация отрабатывает при пустом поле. Проблема заключается в том, что после перезагрузки страницы рендерится уже `storedList: storedPersonalDetailsList`, т.е. данные из хранилища, и валидация больше не отрабатывает. Видимо, это происходит из-за того, что "источник правды" для валидации является массив `propList`, в то время как в шаблоне рендерится `storedList`. Как можно решить данную задачу? Я искренне запутался в том что сделал.

Ссылка на песочницу:
https://replit.com/@teplandrey41/ValidationForm#src/components/BaseForm.vue

**P.S. Удалите из хранилища "ключ: значение" `personalDetailsEducationPanels`, чтобы изначально отрендерился propsList, в котором удачно выводится "error" при пустых полях.**

Answer (score 0):

Делайте предварительную валидацию вводимого пользователем на стороне клиента, используя *Vue* - не будет нагрузки на сервер (для многопользовательского сайта).

И, конечно, упростите себе жизнь с контролем текущего состояния полей! Используйте `Provide`/`Inject` для обмена данными между компонентами.

Comment: Валидация на стороне сервера — это необходимое требование, к сожалению. Что касается provide/inject, я пока не до конца понимаю, как оно может мне здесь помочь. В моем случае, при первом рендеринге передается пропс, который параллельно записывается в хранилище, и все работает. Однако после перезагрузки страницы рендерится массив из хранилища, и валидация не срабатывает.

Comment: Для не особо крупных проектов Хранилище НЕ нужно! И у вас не возникнет "сложностей" с async процессами при запросах на сервер. В главном компоненте получаете с сервера необходимое - далее через  Provide "раздаете" на любую глубину дочерних компонентов - и в них изменение переменной имеет двухстороннюю связь - пропс не нужен. И выбудете иметь единую исходную переменную для полей формы.

Comment: Валидация на сервере - окончательная - обязательно - но то что вводит юзер в формах, проверять СРАЗУ проще. Особенно если это админка - то вы к форме имеете подгруженную/полученную  таблицу в (например  beforeMounted const users = ref({})) и проще делать сразу при вводе в поле делать проверки на "дубликат", "поиск" и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, постараюсь использовать данную информацию в данной ситуации.